# removing one variable from another after having been appended

Tags: jquery

I'm appending an element to the DOM as follows

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    prependIr: function (item) {

        var loading = $('<div class="loading">loading</div>');

        el = $(this);
        item = $(item);
        item.prepend(loading);
        item = el.prepend(item);
        $(item).remove(loading);
    }

});
```

How do I go about removing the loading element from the item variable (I know how to do it via selector in the DOM but is their a neater way doing with the declared objects). In reality this remove will be done after a slight delay.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Try 'loading.remove();' instead.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the item after some delay, use next:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    loading.remove();     
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
// hide it with animation 
//you can also use fadeOut
loading.hide(500, function() {
   //when animation done remove it
   loading.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually You are very close.

only one thing which You must do it's to call directly to loading (this is object):

**loading.remove();**

because after append them, You still have access to them via variable.